# How to prove the consistency of a collection of axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, philosophy, meta-math

Is there a way to prove the consistency of some chosen axioms? In the two senses following:

1. In each mathematical logic book, there is a special kind of deduction system, which include some logical axioms(as opposed to nonlogical axioms). How does the proposer (inventor?) of such a deduction system know that his/her (pure logic) system is consistent?
2. Once a deduction system is founded, one would like to introduce some nonlogical axioms to build a theory. How can one be sure that his/her chosen nonlogical axioms is consistent? For example, how do mathematicians know that the axiom of choice is consistent with the axioms in ZF.

To push the question further, what rules should we follow so as not to fall into inconsistence when we try to choose some axioms for a deduction system and for a theory, and when we try to introduce new nonlogical axioms to a consistent theory?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: To produce a model of the axioms. See e.g. [Geometry axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_geometry#:~:text=Properties%20of%20axiomatic%20systems,-In%20discussing%20axiomatic&text=The%20axioms%20of%20an%20axiomatic,establish%20in%20an%20axiomatic%20system.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the consistency of a theory at least as powerful as the peano axioms cannot be proven within the theory itself (Goedel's second incompleteness theorem). Gentzen used another method to prove the consistency of PA , but it has to be pointed out that even this proof is still circular since it uses transfinite induction which itself would have to be proven consistent.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Then how do you know such a model is consistent? This answer is somewhat kick the can down the road.

Comment: In short, we cannot prove that PA , not alone ZFC , is consistent. But we can prove that adding a new axiom does not produce additional contradictions, which is a kind of relative consistency.

Comment: This is the way: we prove consistency of Euclid's geometry through an "arithmetical" model. We have to start somewhere.

Comment: Only the modern (end 19th Century) development of mathematics has produced the "tools" necessary to **state** the *consistency problem*. Prior to it, no issue at all.

Comment: See also [Gentzen's consistency proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof)

Comment: Logic is something where you can't get something for nothing.  If you want to prove consistency, you must first assume something at least as strong as consistency.  Usually that is the consistency of some other logic.